# Are all these multiple checks really required to handle a new service worker update?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am following a tutorial on service workers on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899) by [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/), and this is the solution skeleton of an exercise on "updating" that has confused me:

[image]

They give a long solution that is like the code below (they check for three possible cases, as explained in comments):

```js
(async() => {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    try {
      const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js");

      if (!reg || !navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        return;
      }
      // Possible states of new updates:
      // - 1. There are no updates yet, a new update may arrive
      // - 2. An update is in progress
      // - 3. A waiting update exists (already installed)
      // 1.
      addEventListener("updatefound", () => {
        console.log("updatefound");
        const sw = reg.installing;
        trackInstallation(sw);
      });
      // 2
      const installingSw = reg.installing;
      if (installingSw) {
        console.log("installingSw");
        trackInstallation(installingSw);
        return;
      }
      // 3
      if (reg.waiting) {
        console.log("reg.waiting");
        const sw = reg.waiting;
        notifyUpdate();
        return;
      }
      console.log("nothing");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Service worker registration failed.", error);
    }
  }
})();

function trackInstallation(worker) {
  worker.addEventListener("statechange", () => {
    if (worker.state === "installed") {
      notifyUpdate();
    }
  });
}

function notifyUpdate() {
  alert("There's a new update!");
}
```

But I tried different scenarios and I can't get these checks except the third one (`if (reg.waiting) {`) to be triggered. So I wonder if all these checks are really needed?

This is how I trigger the third check:

1. Install the service worker (register, install, activate) by loading the web page for the first time at localhost:8080
2. Make a change to the service worker (e.g., add "/tmp.txt" to the array of names of the files that have to be cached)
3. Refresh the page.

First load none of the checks are triggered.

Second load, `reg.waiting` runs (the third check is triggered).

which makes sense (I've read and I know how the lifecycle of service workers works), but I don't know in what scenario the other two checks (i.e., the ones on line 14 and 21) would be triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to remember:

- The service worker isn't for a single page
- The service worker runs independently of any page

In your example code, one page installs the service worker, and ensures that the install completes entirely.

That isn't always the case in the real world. Let's say:

1. You refresh a service-worker-controlled page.
2. That triggers a service worker update check. Assuming an update is found:
3. `// 1` will happen for all pages in the origin. You might not be seeing it, because your code is `addEventListener('updatefound'`, where it should be `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('updatefound'`.
4. If at this point, you reload the page, you might hit `// 2`, since there's already an install in progress.

For more details on the service worker lifecycle, see https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/

Comment: Pardon for asking a bit late, I changed that part of the code to `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('updatefound'` and still `//1` is not happening. I open two tabs (one is duplicated, so both are the same address), then change something in the `sw.js` file, then refresh one page, but the "updatefound" event handler doesn't get triggered in the other tab. If I refresh again in any of the tabs, then again `reg.waiting` happens (`//3`).